# The code in the home page does not show on the front end

Tags: magento-1.9

this code should be working fine last month but just few days ago, i check my website and the layout are change. I do not change any script but suddenly the script are not working anymore, the below are not showing at the front end. I am not sure what it cause. Please advise how to make this code show in the front end or i can use other code to add at the home page. thanks.

```
<div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>
<p><br /> {{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" product_count="12" is_random="1" block_name="Featured Products:" hide_button="1" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" breakpoints="[0, 1], [320, 2], [480, 3], [768, 4], [960, 5], [1280, 6]" pagination="1" centered="1" hide_button="1" block_name="Our Products"}}</p>

<div class="grid12-6 no-left-gutter">{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id="52" product_count="8" breakpoints="[0, 1], [320, 2], [480, 3], [768, 2], [960, 2], [1280, 3]" timeout="4000" centered="1" size="size-s" hide_button="1" block_name="Surveillance"}}</div>

<div class="grid12-6 no-right-gutter">{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id="59" product_count="8" breakpoints="[0, 1], [320, 2], [480, 3], [768, 2], [960, 2], [1280, 3]" timeout="4000" centered="1" size="size-s" hide_button="1" block_name="Self Defense"}}</div>
<div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="grid12-6 no-left-gutter">{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id="66" product_count="8" breakpoints="[0, 1], [320, 2], [480, 3], [768, 2], [960, 2], [1280, 3]" timeout="4000" centered="1" size="size-s" hide_button="1" block_name="Electronics"}}</div>

<div class="grid12-6 no-right-gutter">{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id="75" product_count="8" breakpoints="[0, 1], [320, 2], [480, 3], [768, 2], [960, 2], [1280, 3]" timeout="4000" centered="1" size="size-s" hide_button="1" block_name="Computer & Tables"}}</div>
<div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="grid12-6 no-left-gutter">{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id="85" product_count="8" breakpoints="[0, 1], [320, 2], [480, 3], [768, 2], [960, 2], [1280, 3]" timeout="4000" centered="1" size="size-s" hide_button="1" block_name="Outdoor"}}</div>

<div class="grid12-6 no-right-gutter">{{block type="catalog/product_list_featured_slider" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id="88" product_count="8" breakpoints="[0, 1], [320, 2], [480, 3], [768, 2], [960, 2], [1280, 3]" timeout="4000" centered="1" size="size-s" hide_button="1" block_name="Home & Beauty"}}</div>
```

Please help to advise

---

this is the code that should be working and suddenly it is stop working and not showing at the front end home page. Please help what should i do.

```
<div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>
<p><br /> {{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" product_count="12" is_random="1" block_name="Featured Products:" hide_button="1" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" breakpoints="[0, 1], [320, 2], [480, 3], [768, 4], [960, 5], [1280, 6]" pagination="1" centered="1" hide_button="1" block_name="Our Products"}}</p>

<div class="grid12-6 no-left-gutter">{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id="52" product_count="8" breakpoints="[0, 1], [320, 2], [480, 3], [768, 2], [960, 2], [1280, 3]" timeout="4000" centered="1" size="size-s" hide_button="1" block_name="Surveillance"}}</div>

<div class="grid12-6 no-right-gutter">{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id="59" product_count="8" breakpoints="[0, 1], [320, 2], [480, 3], [768, 2], [960, 2], [1280, 3]" timeout="4000" centered="1" size="size-s" hide_button="1" block_name="Self Defense"}}</div>
<div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="grid12-6 no-left-gutter">{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id="66" product_count="8" breakpoints="[0, 1], [320, 2], [480, 3], [768, 2], [960, 2], [1280, 3]" timeout="4000" centered="1" size="size-s" hide_button="1" block_name="Electronics"}}</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry, this is the script that suddenly stop working and suddenly not showing at the front end home page :

Comment: If it was working a few weeks before, check if you have installed the SUPEE-6788 patch. In that case, you'll need to white-list these blocks from admin to work.